# Нужно ли ставить тире в предложении "А ты к провайдеру звонил - что тебе ответили"?

Tags: пунктуация

А ты к провайдеру звонил - что тебе ответили?

Answer (score 3):

Нет, не нужно.

Обратите внимание, что предлог *к* здесь неуместен. Звонят *кому-то*.

> Ты позвонил провайдеру? Что тебе ответили?
>
> Ты звонил провайдеру, что тебе ответили?

Answer (score 1):

А ты  провайдеру звонил - что тебе ответили?

Это предложение имеет структуру, характерную для устной речи, аналог  следующего варианта: А когда ты  провайдеру звонил, то что тебе ответили?

Поэтому при упрощенной структуре требуется **тире** как более сильный знак, соответствующий  увеличенной паузе в речи.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь два разнородных вопроса (первый предполагает ответ "да/нет", второй требует содержательного ответа), различающихся интонацией. При этом смысл задавать второй вопрос зависит от ответа на первый (звонил или нет). Задав его, нужно либо дождаться кивка, либо мысленно ответить на него самому, сделав вопрос риторическим. Поэтому первый вопрос должен быть *законченным* предложением и на письме передаваться со своим вопросительным знаком - вместо предполагаемого тире. Тире здесь возможно в случае, если первая часть вопроса выражена в утвердительной форме (Ты же звонил провайдеру - ...).

Comment: Alex_ander, а  мне кажется, что говорящий в курсе, что был звонок,  и  просто интересуется ответом. По-моему, это типичная конструкция для лаконичного общения.

Comment: Или вот пример еще пример упрощенного синтаксиса: Ты на выставку ходил - что там интересного? Вам встречались такие конструкции?

Comment: Если он произносит риторический вопрос и при письменной передаче этого не поставить вопросительного знака (что безупречно), то в варианте с тире возможно недопонимание того, каким тоном это сделано: в вашем примере с выставкой первую часть можно прочитать и как утверждение, в то время как риторический вопрос произносится с другой интонацией и зачастую выглядит менее вежливо.

Comment: Риторического вопрос там нет (первая часть утвердительная, она как бы тему задает), просто такая форма общения между хорошо знакомыми людьми.  И интонация очень простая, соответствует присоединительному тире: понижение (не повышение!)  тона перед увеличенной паузой.

Comment: Допускаю, что в первой части исходного вопроса утверждение, но я воспринял  "А ты провайдеру звонил (?)" как вопрос (к этому располагает текст), поскольку  неясность у спросившего была со знаком.